# JQuery 1.6.2 is the .live() function "guilty"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to post a `<form>` in `<div id="contactform">` but it does not work. The debugger does not mention any error and nothing is displayed (the form).

This my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contacts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="recordedit.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="account"></div>

    <h1>Contacts</h1>

    <div id="items"><div id="add"><a href="#" class="add">Add Contact</a></div>
      <div id="contacts"></div>
      <div id="contactform"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the JavaScript code in the helper " recordedit.js " :

```
function contactform(doctoedit) {
    var formhtml;
    formhtml =
        '<form name="update" id="update" action="">';

    if (doctoedit) {
        formhtml = formhtml +
        '<input name="docid" id="docid" type="hidden" value="' + doctoedit._id + '"/>';
    }

    formhtml = formhtml +
    '<table>';

    formhtml = formhtml +
    '<tr><td>Name</td>' +
    '<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="' + (doctoedit ?     doctoedit.name : '') +
    '"/></td></tr>';
    formhtml = formhtml +
    '<tr><td>Phone</td>' +
    '<td><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" value="' + (doctoedit ?     doctoedit.phone : '') +
    '"/></td></tr>';
    formhtml = formhtml + '<tr><td>Email</td>' +
    '<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="' + (doctoedit ? doctoedit.email : '') +
    '"/></td></tr>';

    formhtml = formhtml +
    '</table>' +
    '<input type="submit" name="submit" class="update" value="' + (doctoedit ? 'Update'     : 'Add') + '"/>' +
    '</form>';
    $("#contactform").empty();
    $("#contactform").append(formhtml);
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    updatecontacts();

    $("a.add").live('click', function (event) {
        contactform();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can do $('#add').click(function ... i have several problems with live.

Comment: Even if you did use `.live()`, there's no reason to do it inside a `ready()` callback.

Comment: Try debugging yourself. Add `alert`s (or `console.log`s) in your code to see what's actually executing

Comment: This question can be trivially answered by putting an `alert("foo")` inside your click handler. Do you need someone else to do it?

Comment: Works fine [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gj5hd/) in `1.6.4`

Comment: replace `.live` to `.on`!

Comment: @2astalavista: jQuery 1.6.2 doesn't have `.on()`.

Comment: .live isn't needed here, a.add isn't dynamic.

Comment: @CrazyTrain than replace `jQuery 1.6.2` to `jQuery latest` or pure javascript

Comment: @2astalavista That's not important here, and has nothing to do with the problem we are trying to solve.

Comment: @2astalavista: Things are not that simple. There are significant changes between 1.6.2 and the latest.

Comment: Does `vendor/couchapp/loader.js` synchronously add jQuery? Perhaps `jQuery` is not yet defined (or, `$` is not yet jQuery) when you're trying to register your `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @user: If you have any other handlers bound to the `a.add` elements, or to their ancestors, and if those handlers stop the propagation of the event, then `.live()` won't work.

Comment: I am sure  `updatecontacts()` may have some error.

Comment: @DKM: I thought so too, but OP says there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @CrazyTrain yeah that's true

Comment: Wouldn't be the first OP that said there were no errors when there infact were.

Comment: sorry i don't think that the problem is with updatecontacts()

Comment: @KevinB: Very, very true. It's got to either be errors or a `.stopPropagation()` issue.

Comment: @user2553396 Why don't you try `event.preventDefault()` in `.live()`

Comment: @user2553396: Just as a sanity check, can you remove that function call? Or at least put an `alert("foo")` or `console.log("foo")` right after it?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LtXd8/ if you remove updatecontacts() which is not defined in the fiddle. My guess is an error is occurring in `updatecontacts`.

Comment: @DKM That wouldn't fix anything, as the `<a>`'s `href` is `#`. Although I agree it should be there to prevent the page from scrolling to the top

Comment: @Ian i want facing scroll problem in fiddle that's why i suggested. :)

Comment: @CrazyTrain Look at the function code though. It uses ternary operator to check before accessing properties. And the fiddles in these comments prove it's fine

Comment: @DKM It's a good point, I just don't think it would **fix** anything...that was all :) Still something good to suggest

Comment: Yep, you're right. Noticed the  conditions a little late, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I did the same thing when I first saw the question. I was like "`doctoedit` is undefined so the property access will fail! oh wait, ternaries...". And yeah, right after I commented, I saw you deleted...I just don't like deleting comments, so I kept mine :)

Comment: @scrappedcola What's that matter? If you omit the `action` or provide an empty value, the default is just the current page's URL

Answer (score 0):

IT WORKS: http://jsfiddle.net/RWDRw/

You should include jquery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```